# Unset all data except the data associated with a given value in url

Tags: php

I have a file that sends a request through curl, when I hit the url which is formatted as http://www.example.com/api/something?id=24 I get a series of arrays back in JSON form. It looks like:

```
24: {
    pe: {
        id: "24",
        name: "Blah",
        engine_src: "blah",
        each_lender: "1",
        soap_request: "0",
        lenders: {
               0: "3",
               1: "1",
               2: "6",
               3: "12"
        }
   },
   lenders: {
            0: {
              id: "1",
              platform_id: "2",
              lender_id: "3",
              engine_id: "24",
              status: "1",
              engine_lender_id: "3",
              engine_lender_name: "choice #1"
   },
}
```

There are several other numbers and arrays in the list that look similar. I need to return the array that is associated with the id in the url and only that array.

I have set a new variable which looks like

```
$selected = (int)$_REQUEST['pe'];
```

How do I unset all other values except what is in my $selected variable?

Comment: A bit more detail would help - is the structure consistent, where pe only has one element, and lenders always has an array? Or is it variable structures?

If it's variable, it seems like you'd need to first find the 'id' key, using something like this: Search for a key in an array, recursively then return if a match on your id. But I'm not sure exactly what you'd want to see returned - is it the other values in that element? The parent element with the id and its values? something else? When you respond, can probably update this answer to give more specific approaches.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out. Yes the structure is consistent. pe always only has one element, and lenders always has an array of at least one. What I'm wanting to see returned is the entire array that corresponds to the id given in the URL. So if I had entered id=24 in the URL I would want to see the entire array that I posted above back and only that array I wouldn't want to see an array that started with 25 {} for example.

Comment: Ok, just because there's multiple 24's there...is it the first 24, where it is      24: { ... }?, or do you need to find the id:"24" at the pe level to determine which array?

Comment: O ya, sorry for that confusion. I'm referencing the very first 24, not the id: "24".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, then, assuming your response is in the variable $jsonresponse...

```
$selected = json_decode($jsonresponse,$assoc=TRUE);
$selected = $selected[$id];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help Charlene. This is how I ended up solving the problem. It is the same concept that Charlene posted just a slightly different format.

```
$selected = (int)$_REQUEST['pe'];
$save_me = $data[$selected];
unset($data);
$data = $save_me;
print_r($data);
```